# SQL Query to update DE field when "x" hours away from date/time field which is already formatted to the correct timezone

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sql, automationstudio, datetime

We are working on building a journey that is extremely dependent on utilizing a date/time field (`StartDateTime`) to determine when emails/sms are delivered. Given the constraints in Journey Builder when it comes to the ability to wait until "x" hours before the field value, we are looking to build an SQL Query within the automation studio to update a boolean field that lives in the same DE that triggers the journey from false > true.

The issue I am running into when attempting to build this Query is that the `StartDateTime` field is already formatted to the timezone of the Contact it is associated with. This has led me to believe that we would run into issues unless we configure the datediff logic to account for each specific timezone value given I am unsure what timezone the SFMC SQL Activity defaults to.

Here is the general idea of what I'm looking to accomplish:

```
    SELECT
    s.ID,
    s.StartDateTime as 'StartTime',
    s.Timezone as 'TimeZone',
    FROM 
    **DE Name**
    WHERE
    TimeZone = **Insert Time Zone**
    AND
    datediff(hh,cd.starttime,Now() <= **Number of hours based on Timezone value**
    OR
    Process continues
```

For reference, here is how our StartDateTime field is structured:

```
2024-03-04 09:30:00.000
```

Wondering if anyone has ideas as to how to go about accomplishing this logic. Any help/ideas are appreciated!

Comment: Looks like SQL evaluates in UTC -6 for the TZ so maybe I wont have to worry about all the timezones when building in the logic.